# React Native notification scheduled for 2 months

Tags: react-native

I am building an app in React Native with Expo that creates a push notification to appear 2 months after tapping a button. Is it possible to achieve this solely in the React Native app, or would it require a backend service of some kind?

I see a [scheduled notification example in Notifee](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/triggers), but would this be able to persist for 2 months?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library such as [React-Native-Push-Notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) to schedule a local notification. However, with iOS, you can only schedule a notification monthly, not for every x number of months.

If you want more custom logic for the scheduling of the notification, I would recommend using a notification service such as Notifee as you mentioned, or running a cron job using a backend service.